# Load different date formats in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, date-format, mysql-5.0

I have a date field in my datafile which I am trying to load in MySQL, but the date field is in dd-mon-yy format and MySQL only understands YYYY-MM-DD.

Is there a way by which I can load DD-MON-YY data into YYYY-MM-DD format using MySQL LOAD or any other native utility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not difficult. Just need a `set` section in your `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.

```
mysql> create table tst ( datecol datetime );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql>
```

File:

```
[root@node1 ~]# cat /tmp/tst.dat
01-JAN-03
21-MAR-09
28-FEB-11
[root@node1 ~]#
```

Test:

```
mysql> load data infile '/tmp/tst.dat'
    -> into table tst
    -> fields terminated by '|'
    -> lines terminated by '\n'
    -> (@datecol)
    -> set
    -> datecol = str_to_date(@datecol, '%d-%M-%y');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from tst;
+---------------------+
| datecol             |
+---------------------+
| 2003-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2009-03-21 00:00:00 |
| 2011-02-28 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: @user2118349 That's ok. If you found the answer helpful, please mark it as accepted by clicking the "tick" at the top-left.